# Cannot read message from client : UDP python 3

Tags: python, tcp, udp

I tried to send message to server from client with manual input, with 10 limits input. its succesfully work on client side but when i tried to run server it's shows nothing

here's the code from client side

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost"

UDP_PORT = 50026

print ("Destination IP:", UDP_IP)
print ("Destination port:", UDP_PORT)


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


for x in range (10):

    data = input("Message: ")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print(data)
else :
    print("lebih dari 10!!")

    s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

s.close()
```

here's result and code from server side

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost"

UDP_PORT = 50026

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


while True:

    data, address = s.recvfrom(1024)

    print(data)
    print(address)


s.close()
```

when i run the program, nothing happen.  here's the running program [image: The result]

Comment: You are only sending data in the `else` block which is not executed.

Comment: do you have reference for that? im new in python

Comment: Well, you wrote the `else`. What did you except to happen there?

Comment: to show limit of input, when the input more than 10

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the else statement you added there which is not executing. If want to put a limit of 10 after accepting the input, you are supposed to print the statement after the loop.

This is the client code:

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1" # It is the same as localhost.
UDP_PORT = 50026

print ("Destination IP:", UDP_IP)
print ("Destination port:", UDP_PORT)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for x in range (10):
    data = input("Message: ")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    print(data)
    s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print("lebih dari 10!!")
s.close()
```

Edit:

I am not really understanding your problem but as far as I understand you want to show the limit on the server. Thus you can do this, try adding a loop on the server and receive input from the client's address only to avoid receiving extra messages.

Server Code:

```py
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1" # It is the same as localhost.

UDP_PORT = 50026

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

x = 0
while True:
    data, address = s.recvfrom(1024)
    # This block will make sure that the packets you are receiving are from expected address

    # The address[0] returns the ip of the packet's address, address is actually = ('the ip address', port)
    if address[0] != '127.0.0.1':
        continue
    # The logic block ends
    print(data)
    print(address)
    x = x + 1 # This shows that one more message is received.
    if x == 10:
        break # This breaks out of the loop and then the remaining statements will execute ending the program

print("10 messages are received and now the socket is closing.")
s.close()
print("Socket closed")
```

I have commented the code so I hope you understand the code

Comment: yeah but it's still dont show the message from client side in server